# Convert string to date with format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z'

Tags: c#

My string of date is '2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z' and i am unable to convert it to datetime.

I have tried

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(DOCDate, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Does '2018-12-30' look like it is "dd.MM.yyyy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does now work, is that the date in your string is in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` format, and the format you specify to `ParseExact` is `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z`. That way the date could not be parsed.

Comment: with this format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ' it also showing me same error .

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeOffset.Parse("2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z");` seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
  string s="2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z";
   DateTime da=     DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   Response.Write(da.ToString());
```

Try this

Comment: It showing error msg of 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' because of 'z' in string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.TryParse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) with [DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to have the exact same time, or `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` to adjust to the Local Time:

```
 bool result = DateTime.TryParse("2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateTime dt);

=> 12/30/2018 18:30:00 or 30/12/2018 18:30:00 (...)

 bool result = DateTime.TryParse("2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime dt);

=> 30/12/2018 [Adjusted to your Local time] (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you a string in desired format

(DateTime.Parse("2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z" )).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff z");

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateString="2018-12-30T18:30:00.000z";
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString));
```

See the Output of in the image below it's working
[image]